# rails migration after custom foreign key change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, migration

I have this problem which I can't figure out.

I have 2 tables:

```
class NotificationTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_notifications
end

class SentNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notification_template
end
```

No belongs to table have this line:

```
belongs_to :notification_template, foreign_key: "template_id"
```

The difficult part is that `NotificationTemplate` have translation table, which stores previous foreign key. Is there a way to change both thous foreign keys. Because I can't access that translation table trough `ActiveRecord`.

**EDIT:**

I created this 2 models, and ran migrations without `foreign_key: "template_id"` do rails generated default `foreign_key`, which is `notification_template_id`. Which is too long for me. So now I changed foreign key in model and need to create a migration which will change all of the tables foreign keys for this association. Is there some kind of way to do this, without rename_column migration for all associations?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question.  Your subject and tags suggestion you're asking with regard to a migration, but your post doesn't mention that.  Could you elaborate more on exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I edited, maybe that will clear thing out.